# Open tcp port 5432 for postgresql mac

Tags: macos, postgresql, tcp, remote-access

I want to open a tcp port (5432) on a mac server to remotely using sql.

I installed psql9.4 using brew.

Initially I tried:

> Open /etc/pf.conf in a text editor.
>
> Add a line like this:
>
> pass in proto tcp from any to any port 5432
>
> Save the file.
>
> Load the changes (and test them) with:
>
> sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
>
> Reboot.

I used network utility to check if the port was opened. But no luck.

Then I downloaded IceFloor.
I added custom Rules:

> pass on en0 net photo tcp from any to any port =5432 flags S/SA keep state

Also added a new custom service to PFLists Service Database:

> service name: PSQL
>
> ports 5432

Still no luck...

Any suggestions?

Thank you